# How to change namingStrategy in springdoc?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, springdoc

I am using [`springdoc`](https://springdoc.org/#modules). It works flawlessly, except I am trying to change the default camelCase to PascalCase requests mapping.

I searched through the docs and cannot find a configuration to adjust property naming.

How can I change property naming when working with `springdoc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Debargha Roy mentioned in his answer, there is no clear way to do it via `springdoc` properties.

I propose my solution for Kotlin based on [GitHub thread](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/66).

To get `PascalCase` or `UpperCamelCase` in Swagger, you can use `ModelResolver`:

```
@Bean
fun modelResolver(objectMapper: ObjectMapper): ModelResolver {
    return ModelResolver(jacksonObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule()).setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE))
}
```

It doesn't resolve the output response from Spring `@RestController`.

By default, Spring uses Jackson mapper to make responses follow UpperCamelCase, use this property `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=UPPER_CAMEL_CASE` in properties/yaml file.

After these 2 changes, both your Swagger and RestController will follow the UpperCamelCase style.

**NOTE:**

Beware, if you decided to reuse incoming `objectMapper` (see the snippet below), you may get duplicated payload with mixed camelCase:

```
@Bean
fun modelResolver(objectMapper: ObjectMapper): ModelResolver {
    return ModelResolver(objectMapper.registerModule(KotlinModule()).setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Dmytro Chasovskyi solution above also worked for me on SpringDoc.

I'm on java Spring though, all I had to do:

```
@Bean
public ModelResolver modelResolver(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
  return new ModelResolver(objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategies.SNAKE_CASE));
}
```

Comment: It's the same solution but looks simpler as it doesn't require Kotlin constructs.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not do it. The reason being that there's no way to change the name of the request handler by using the Swagger annotations.

And lowerCamelCase for method/identifier names is promoted by the [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) and also by the [Google Naming Convention](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s5-naming).

You should still be able to compile and run the code if you don't follow the conventions. Other than that, I don't think there's an official way of changing the method name's case using Swagger directly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this might be useful for someone else, I had to use:

```
  import io.swagger.v3.core.util.Json;
  @Bean
  public ModelResolver modelResolverDefault() {
    ObjectMapper copy = Json.mapper().copy();
    return new ModelResolver(copy.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE));
  }
```

Although the default solution does work for snake case, I lost field description and examples, by using the springdoc default mapper as a copy everything worked.

Please note that when I tried without the copy springdoc stopped working with an error related to additional_fields in camelcase.