# Spring Doc Open API swagger UI is not displaying attribute in snake case

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, springdoc

Spring Doc Open API swagger UI is not displaying attribute in snake case.
I am using below configs

```
implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui', version: '1.6.5'
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "Samples API", version = "1",
        description = "This is a sample api with Open API"),
        servers = { @Server(url = "/", description = "Default URL")})
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=snake_case
```

But the request body attribute is coming in camel case.
If I add the below, request body attribute is coming in snake case.

```
@Bean
public ModelResolver modelResolver(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
     return new ModelResolver(objectMapper);
}
```

How can achieve the same using a property or an annotation

Comment: The same problem here :)

Comment: I didnt see a way to specify snake case in their documentation [Link](https://springdoc.org/)

Comment: Created an issue with spring docs [issue1507](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/1507)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution (configure a ModelResolver bean) here:

- [How to change namingStrategy in springdoc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67192746/how-to-change-namingstrategy-in-springdoc)

More details here:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/66

I'm using java Spring so this is all I needed:

```
@Bean
public ModelResolver modelResolver(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
  return new ModelResolver(objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategies.SNAKE_CASE));
}
```