# Deserialization of snake_case to camel_case in spring boot with openapi generator

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, deserialization, openapi-generator

In our spring boot service, we are using open API to generate the contracts and the interface which our rest controller can implement.

However, in the request body, the fields are in snake case but the fields in the Java class are in camel case and as a result, all the deserialized fields in the created object become null.

Here is the request object.

```
 {
   "car": {
            "total_price": 21300,
            "color": "blue",
            "year_and_model": "Ford 2021"
           }
 }
```

and my generated car class looks like

```
@Schema(name = "Car", description = "Car request payload")
@Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2023-12-06T10:01:37.820309+02:00[Europe/Helsinki]")
public class Car {

  private Long totalPrice;

  private String color;

  private String yearAndModel;

}
```

I have added `spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE` in `application.properties` and also tried with the following solutions

- Add the following build.gradle

```
"additionalModelTypeAnnotations": "@com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonNaming(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)"
```

to `configOptions.set([])` in `openApiGenerate`

- Add added a bean for ModelResolver as some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67192746/how-to-change-namingstrategy-in-springdoc) suggest

```
@Bean
   public ModelResolver modelResolver(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
     return new ModelResolver(objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategies.SNAKE_CASE));
}
```

But none of the solutions work. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that ALL deserialized fields in the created object become null. This means that you have no problem with converting snake case to camel case but with your model. The field `color` would be set otherwise - it is not in snake case.

To get an object correctly mapped from the JSON provided in your question you should model the Java classes (DTO) like this:

```java
public class CarDto {
  private Car car;
}
public class Car {
  private Long totalPrice;
  private String color;
  private String yearAndModel;
}
```

Don't forget to implement getters and setters. They are essential for Jackson JSON mapper used by Spring.

In addition to this you need to tell Spring to convert from snake to camel case by one of following options:

Option 1 - set the global property:

```
spring.jackson.property-naming-strategy=SNAKE_CASE
```

Option 2 - configure the global object mapper:

```java
@Bean
ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
}
```